# Single-use class

Tags: c++, class, design-patterns

In a project I am working on, we have several "disposable" classes. What I mean by disposable is that they are a class where you call some methods to set up the info, and you call what equates to a `doit` function. You `doit` once and throw them away. If you want to `doit` again, you have to create another instance of the class. The reason they're not reduced to single functions is that they must store state for after they `doit` for the user to get information about what happened and it seems to be not very clean to return a bunch of things through reference parameters. It's not a singleton but not a normal class either.

Is this a bad way to do things? Is there a better design pattern for this sort of thing? Or should I just give in and make the user pass in a boatload of reference parameters to return a bunch of things through?

Comment: You can accomplish the same thing by passing in a reference to struct, which the function will fill up with the results of its execution.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that. Is there not a more C++'ish way?

Comment: @Seth: What's not "C++'ish" about it?

Comment: It could be perfectly C++'ish, it just feels more like C than C++ to me. If that's the best way though then I guess that's it.

Comment: @Seth: Sometimes the C-ish way is better than the OOP way. If it works best, use it

Comment: @Seth - if you want to be "C++"ish, you can return the struct by value.

Comment: That sounds *exactly* like a functor. Only without the superfluous `doit` name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like your class is basically a parameter block in a thin disguise.

There's nothing wrong with that IMO, and it's certainly better than a function with so many parameters it's hard to keep track of which is which.

It can also be a good idea when there's a lot of input parameters - several setup methods can set up a few of those at a time, so that the names of the setup functions give more clue as to which parameter is which. Also, you can cover different ways of setting up the same parameters using alternative setter functions - either overloads or with different names. You might even use a simple state-machine or flag system to ensure the correct setups are done.

<strike>However, it should really be possible to recycle your instances without having to delete and recreate. A "reset" method, perhaps.</strike>

- As Konrad suggests, this is perhaps misleading. The reset method shouldn't be seen as a replacement for the constructor - it's the constructors job to put the object into a self-consistent initialised state, not the reset methods. Object should be self-consistent at all times.
- Unless there's a reason for making cumulative-running-total-style do-it calls, the caller should never have to call reset explicitly - it should be built into the do-it call as the first step.
- **I still decided, on reflection, to strike that out** - not so much because of Jalfs comment, but because of the hairs I had to split to argue the point ;-) - Basically, I figure I almost always have a reset method for this style of class, partly because my "tools" usually have multiple related kinds of "do it" (e.g. "insert", "search" and "delete" for a tree tool), and shared mode. The mode is just some input fields, in parameter block terms, but that doesn't mean I want to keep re-initializing. **But just because this pattern happens a lot for me, doesn't mean it should be a point of principle.**

I even have a name for these things (not limited to the single-operation case) - "tool" classes. A "tree_searching_tool" will be a class that searches (but doesn't contain) a tree, for example, though in practice I'd have a "tree_tool" that implements several tree-related operations.

Basically, even parameter blocks in C should ideally provide a kind of abstraction that gives it some order beyond being just a bunch of parameters. "Tool" is a (vague) abstraction. Classes are a major means of handling abstraction in C++.

Comment: “However, it should really be possible to recycle your instances without having to delete and recreate” – why? This is bad advice, it runs counter the lifecycle of a class. I know that enough C++ classes copy this bad design (`std::fstream`) but that doesn’t mean one should adopt it. Class instances should be strictly single-use. If you need a new one, create a new one. This makes architectures easier and reduces error potential since the state of an object is always well-defined (= properly initialised).

Comment: @Konrad - do you automatically throw away your screwdriver after screwing in precisely one screw? No. There's no automatic implication, in either "tool" or "parameter block", that it should only be used to "do it" once. A class should hold one single "thing" - but if that "thing" is a "tool", there's no contradiction there. More pragmatically, if you're in an inner loop, you probably want to minimise clutter from e.g. parameter block declarations at that level.

Comment: That’s a false analogy. The “real” analogy is that once you’ve used a screwdriver it is now in an undefined limbo state and needs to be sent back to the factory for re-initialisation before it can be reused. And now you need to keep track of whether a screwdriver is currently in a well-defined state (without any indication of that), otherwise it will explode upon usage. I also don’t understand, or completely disagree, with your “pragmatic” argument. You should always limit scope as much as possible. This entails declaring variables in the innermost scope, i.e. inside a loop, if possible.

Comment: As for "always well defined", who says it isn't? Maybe calling "do-it" again just accumulates more, so that calling "reset" is a bit like assigning zero to a running total - even if you don't reset, you still have a valid self-consistent state with more "do-it" calls permitted. I didn't say it, but of course if "do-it" is expected to start from scratch every time, it *can* (and *should*) just handle that every time - maybe calling that "reset" method itself. If you view "reset" as creating the initial minimally-self-consistent state, that is what constructors are for, not "reset" methods.

Comment: @Konrad - the hassles of typing speed and comment-size limits. I agree that it's bad to have non-self-consistent objects. I disagree that an object is in a non-self-consistent "limbo state" just because it has been used once.

Comment: @Steve314: if there was zero cost to discarding my screwdriver, then yes, I would *absolutely* throw it away. Why would I intentionally use an old, worn screwdriver, if there's no cost to getting a shiny new one each time?

Comment: @Steve: The OP *said* that the object is intended to be used once. Its purpose, and the abstraction it models, is that of a "single use" object. Yes, you can work around that, yes, you can allow it to be called again, but that happens at the cost of more complexity, in that you have to reset the object to a valid state between uses, and more scope for error, and that you probably have to give the object a much larger lifetime, which is harder to reason about.

Comment: @jalf - agreed, that's true, at least to a point. But requirements change and refactoring happens, and being able to reset things is just so commonly useful when it turns out to be convenient to use that same screwdriver twice after all. For efficiency, very often a "do-it" method will simply overwrite all fields. All the "reset" will do is ensure that any fields needing to be zerod out (or similar) get that. The constructor at least will need to do that anyway - e.g. by calling that reset method.

Comment: @jalf - as a rule I agree with agile principles and complexity-in-the-call-graph-is-still-complexity, but having reset methods is usually both trivial and natural - why have an idiom for single-use and an idiom for multi-use when both are so similar, and multi-use can do both jobs anyway?

Comment: @jalf - also, on principle, you should never *have* a "worn out" screwdriver. In software, that implies a non-self-consistent state, which risks confusing destructors, causing problems with exception safety etc. OK, you know these things won't happen in some special cases, but in principle... and after maintenance and refactoring...

Comment: @Steve: that makes no sense. Why manually implement a reset method, *no matter how trivial*, if I can get the same functionality for free by just creating a new object? And on the second part, you're mixing up arguments. The "worn out" part simply implies "it has been used before, and it won't be in its initial state unless I manually write code to put it into that state". I didn't say "unusable", or even "worn out", but simply "worn". The difference is pretty significant.

Comment: I'm certainly not proposing putting your objects in an inconsistent state. On the contrary, I'm saying "you shouldn't have the intermediate state *at all*, if it doesn't serve a purpose". If you let the object go out of scope after use, and create a new one when you need it, then the intermediate state **doesn't exist**, and all headaches about "is it in a valid state? Did I remember to reset everything" just vanish.

Comment: And one more point. Simply stating something as a fact doesn't make it a fact. Why exactly is it "so commonly useful" to be able to reset an object, over simply letting it be destroyed and recreating it? Is it really such a common use case that it justifies adding that plumbing even to classes where you don't know if you're ever going to need it?

Comment: @jalf - actually, on reflection, I agree - see edit in answer.

Comment: Wow, this was a very enlightening thread of conversation. Thanks for all the effort, I didn't expect this much thought to be put into answering this question.

Answer (score 4):

What you describe is ***not a class*** (state + methods to alter it), ***but an algorithm*** (map input data to output data):

```
result_t do_it(parameters_t);
```

Why do you think you need a class for that?

Answer (score 2):

I have used a [similar design](http://code.google.com/p/tetris-challenge/source/browse/trunk/Tetris/include/Tetris/NodeCalculator.h) and wondered about this too. A fictive simplified example could look like this:

```
FileDownloader downloader(url);
downloader.download();
downloader.result(); // get the path to the downloaded file
```

To make it reusable I store it in a `boost::scoped_ptr`:

```
boost::scoped_ptr<FileDownloader> downloader;

// Download first file
downloader.reset(new FileDownloader(url1));
downloader->download();

// Download second file
downloader.reset(new FileDownloader(url2));
downloader->download();
```

To answer your question: I think it's ok. I have not found any problems with this design.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell you are describing a class that represents an algorithm. You configure the algorithm, then you run the algorithm and then you get the result of the algorithm. I see nothing wrong with putting those steps together in a class if the alternative is a function that takes 7 configuration parameters and 5 output references.

This structuring of code also has the advantage that you can split your algorithm into several steps and put them in separate private member functions. You can do that without a class too, but that can lead to the sub-functions having many parameters if the algorithm has a lot of state. In a class you can conveniently represent that state through member variables.

One thing you might want to look out for is that structuring your code like this could easily tempt you to use inheritance to share code among similar algorithms. If algorithm A defines a private helper function that algorithm B needs, it's easy to make that member function protected and then access that helper function by having class B derive from class A. It could also feel natural to define a third class C that contains the common code and then have A and B derive from C. As a rule of thumb, inheritance used only to share code in non-virtual methods is not the best way - it's inflexible, you end up having to take on the data members of the super class and you break the encapsulation of the super class. As a rule of thumb for that situation, prefer factoring the common code out of both classes without using inheritance. You can factor that code into a non-member function or you might factor it into a utility class that you then use without deriving from it.

YMMV - what is best depends on the specific situation. Factoring code into a common super class is the basis for the [template method pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), so when using virtual methods inheritance might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing especially wrong with the concept.  You should try to set it up so that the objects in question can generally be auto-allocated vs having to be newed -- significant performance savings in most cases.  And you probably shouldn't use the technique for highly performance-sensitive code unless you know your compiler generates it efficiently.

Comment: Is there a way to define a class that cannot be allocated on the stack, but *can* be allocated on the heap? I understand there's some design issues that can make allocation on the stack problematic, but everything I can think of off the top of my head is a how-it's-used issue rather than a how-it's-defined issue. Also, a class with a method is no slower than a function taking a pointer/reference to a struct - *unless* you're using run-time binding or run-time type identification for some reason. Passing the `this` parameter is no faster/slower than passing any other pointer parameter.

Comment: @Steve: to make a class that can't be created on the stack, make its ctor private then provide a public factory function that creates an instance on the heap and returns it.

Comment: It's mostly a case of making it usable when stack allocated, and not having unnecessary dynamically allocated pieces inside it, though Mac describes ways to make stack allocation actually impossible.  A class with non-virtual methods and no destructor is no slower than a struct (which can have its own methods) on any sensible system, but virtual methods and destructors can be quite expensive in some architectures.

Answer (score 0):

I disagree that the class you're describing "is not a normal class".  It has state and it has behavior.  You've pointed out that it has a relatively short lifespan, but that doesn't make it any less of a class.

**Short-lived classes vs. functions with out-params**:
I agree that your short-lived classes are probably a little more intuitive and easier to maintain than a function which takes many out-params (or 1 complex out-param).  However, I suspect a function will perform slightly better, because you won't be taking the time to instantiate a new short-lived object.  If it's a simple class, that performance difference is probably negligible.  However, if you're talking about an extremely performance-intensive environment, it might be a consideration for you.

**Short-lived classes: creating new vs. re-using instances**: 
There's plenty of examples where instances of classes are re-used: thread-pools, DB-connection pools (probably darn near any software construct ending in 'pool' :).  In my experience, they seem to be used when instantiating the object is an expensive operation.  Your small, short-lived classes don't sound like they're expensive to instantiate, so I wouldn't bother trying to re-use them.  You may find that whatever pooling mechanism you implement, actually costs MORE (performance-wise) than simply instantiating new objects whenever needed.